# error collate con bases de datos

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo dos bases de datos que han sido definidas con collation distintos:

```
multi ---> SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
report --> SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS
```

necesito cruzar tablas de ambas bases de datos pero me da error:

la consulta que trato de ejecutar:

```
  SELECT CONCAT('vtex-',D.externalOrderNumber,D.folio) as boleta 
  FROM [report].[dbo].[MOD_WEB] AS WEB 
  INNER JOIN multi.dbo.DataIn AS D ON WEB.ORDR =  D.DocentryPedido
  WHERE ID_MOD_WEB = 739914
```

El error que obtengo :

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between
>   "SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in
>   the concat operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server no resuelve de manera automática las conversiones entre un *collate* y otro, por esto mismo, cuándo hay operaciones con columnas con diferente colación, debes indicar explicitamente qué columna(s) quieres *convertir* de su colación actual a otra para que se realice la operación, sea esta una comparación, concatenación u otra que abarque varias columnas.

Entonces, asumo que las colaciones actuales para la concatenación son:

```
D.externalOrderNumber     SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS
D.folio                   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

y queremos que la concatenación se realice en `SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS`, debemos entonces escribir:

```
SELECT CONCAT('vtex-', D.externalOrderNumber, D.folio collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS) as boleta 
  FROM [report].[dbo].[MOD_WEB] AS WEB 
       INNER JOIN multi.dbo.DataIn AS D ON WEB.ORDR =  D.DocentryPedido 
WHERE ID_MOD_WEB = 739914
```

De manera general, para *forzar* la conversión de una columna que está almacenada en una colación a otra, escribimos el nombre de la columna, la palabra `collate` seguida del nombre de la colación a la que queremos convertirla.

Si, por el contrario, quisieramos realizar la concatenación en `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`, entonces haríamos la conversión en la columna `D.externalOrderNumber`, de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT CONCAT('vtex-', D.externalOrderNumber collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, D.folio) as boleta 
  FROM [report].[dbo].[MOD_WEB] AS WEB 
       INNER JOIN multi.dbo.DataIn AS D ON WEB.ORDR =  D.DocentryPedido 
WHERE ID_MOD_WEB = 739914
```

Parece una decisión arbitraria, pero debes tomar en cuenta que las conversiones entre un collate y otro pueden dar resultados diferentes, ya que hay caracteres que no existen o son valorados de distinta manera entre una colación y otra. Esto es particularmente importante para las operaciones de comparación.

No olvides que estoy asumiendo las colaciones de las columnas, si el código no te funciona directamente, consulta para verificar en que colación está cada una y ajusta el código de acuerdo a esa información.