# Problema con Convert y COLLATE SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

estoy uniendo una serie de querys, el problema es que en uno de ellos me presenta el siguiente error

***Cannot resolve collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in UNION ALL operator occurring in SELECT statement column 7***

lo raro es que el campo que estoy agregando no tiene nada solo esta en duro

```
SELECT
''  AS [Nº Tarjeta/Prestamo] 
FROM prueba
```

tengo mas campos pero el problema es justo con ese, logre solucionarlo asi

```
SELECT
'' collate database_default  AS [Nº Tarjeta/Prestamo] 
FROM prueba
```

Pero ahora me arroja este error

***Error converting data type varchar to numeric***

al intentar convertir a `Numeric`

```
CAST('' AS NUMERIC(15)) collate database_default     AS [Nº Tarjeta/Prestamo]
```

me sale este error

***Expression type numeric is invalid for COLLATE clause***

entonces que puede estar pasando? como puedo solucionar ese problema?

Comment: El collate o codificación es solo para valores tipo cadena, un numérico no tiene collate.

Comment: No puedes convertir a numeric un valor que no es numeric.`CAST('' AS NUMERIC(15)) collate database_default     AS [Nº Tarjeta/Prestamo] `. Cambia por `CAST(xxxxx AS NUMERIC(15))      AS [Nº Tarjeta/Prestamo]`. Donde xxxxx tiene que ser un valor convertible a numeric. También puedes utilizar try_cast, que si no puede convertirlo, te devolverá un null `TRY_CAST('' AS NUMERIC(15))      AS [Nº Tarjeta/Prestamo] `

Comment: No me funciono ninguna, no se que mas hacer

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [error collate con bases de datos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/299650/error-collate-con-bases-de-datos)